# validating contact form using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

hey guys i was working on a contact form for my college and i want to validate the contact form but it doesnt seem to be working! can anyone help me on this!

here is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript"> 
    function validateMyForm ( ) { 
    var isValid = true;
    var name = document.getElementsByName("Name");
    var email = document.getElementsByName("Email");
    var phone = document.getElementsByName("Phone");
    if ( name == "" ) { 
        alert ( "Please enter your Name" ); 
        isValid = false;
    } else if ( email == "" ) { 
            alert ( "Please enter your Email ID" ); 
            isValid = false;
    } else if ( phone == "" ) { 
            alert ( "Please enter your Phone Number" ); 
            isValid = false;
    }   
    return isValid;
}
</script>
```

Body part:

```
<h3>Contact form:</h3>
<form id="contact-form" method="post">
<fieldset>
<label class="name">
<font color='black'><b><span>Name:</span></b></font><input type="text" id="Name" name="Name"></label>
<label class="email">
<font color='black'><b><span>Email ID:</span></b></font><input type="email" id="Email" name="Email"></label>
<label class="phone"><font color='black'><b><span>Phone:</span></b></font><input type="text" id="Phone" name="Phone"></label>
<label class="message">
<font color='black'><b><span>Queries:</span></b></font><textarea></textarea></label><br><br>
<div class="btns">
<button id="submit" name="submit" onclick="javascript:return validateMyForm();">Send</button> &nbsp 
<button onClick="document.getElementById('contact-form').reset()">Clear</button>
</div>
</fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: Welcome to the site! What isn't working? Please read about [**How to Ask questions here**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var name = document.getElementsByName("Name");
```

That gets a list of elements with name of "name".

```
var name = document.getElementsByName("Name")[0].value;
```

That gets the first of the elements with name of "name", then gets the value. You should change all 3 of them.

If you want to have it go by the id, not the name, you can use:

```
var name = document.getElementById("Name").value;
```

If you want it to go by name, but not the first in the page, rather the first in the form, use this:

```
var name = document.getElementById('contact-form').getElementsByName("Name")[0].value;
```